# Why access token has no longer expiry time?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, refresh-token

I am trying to implement Oauth2 with Jwt in my Application. One doubt I am having is why do I need to have lesser expiry time to `access_token` and a longer expiry time to `refresh_token`.

What I mean to say is I can have an `access_token` with a longer expiry time and I would protect `access_token` like I am protecting the `refresh_token`, there is no need to `refresh_token` only. Does that make sense?

So if I am ignoring refresh_token from my application, would I face any usability issue or security issue?

Comment: `Access token` allow an application to access a service. It should be included in each request header to get access to the service, So it has high chance of getting logged by the server or proxies. If it has long expiry it could be later used to access the service(may be on behalf of the original user). `Refresh token` is not included in the headers and is used in POST request only to get the access token. So falling a `refresh token` into wrong hands is less likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5):

> **1.5.  Refresh Token**
>
> Refresh tokens are credentials used to obtain access tokens.  Refresh
> tokens are issued to the client by the authorization server and are
> used to obtain a new access token when the current access token
> becomes invalid or expires, or to obtain additional access tokens
> with identical or narrower scope (access tokens may have a shorter
> lifetime and fewer permissions than authorized by the resource
> owner).  Issuing a refresh token is optional at the discretion of the
> authorization server.  If the authorization server issues a refresh
> token, it is included when issuing an access token (i.e., step (D) in
> Figure 1).
>
> A refresh token is a string representing the authorization granted to
> the client by the resource owner.  The string is usually opaque to
> the client.  The token denotes an identifier used to retrieve the
> authorization information.  Unlike access tokens, refresh tokens are
> intended for use only with authorization servers and are never sent
> to resource servers.